# How is memory allocated to array of const char*

Tags: char

Memory is allocted in a contiguous manner in integer array. But then how is it allocated to a array of strings.

Suppose I have array of string like this:

`const char *A[] = {"abcx" , "dbba" , "cccc"};`

does every character of string get its own address. Something like this:

```
1000 -> a
1001 -> b
1002 -> c
1003 -> x
1004 -> \0
1005 -> d
1006 -> b
1007 -> b
1008 -> a
1009 -> \0
.
.
```

When I perform this operation.

```
char var = *(A+1) - *A + 1;
cout<<(*A+var)<<endl;
```

> Output: 'bba'

So what is happening under the hood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const char *A[] = {"abcx" , "dbba" , "cccc"};` is not an array of strings. It is an array of pointers to strings.

For each of `"abcx"`, `"dbba"`, and `"cccc"`, the compiler creates and initializes an array of `char`, and it assigns memory for those arrays, commonly in a read-only data section of the program. They might be next to each other in that order, they might be in a different order, or they might be scattered and mingled with other data.

Then `const char *A[]` defines `A` to be an array of pointers to `char`. The compiler will figure out how many elements are in that array when it counts the initializers, and it will allocate space for that array. Since there are three initializers, it will provide space for three elements of type `char *`.

Then `= {"abcx" , "dbba" , "cccc"}` will cause the compiler to initialize each array element to the first character of the corresponding string.

The total space for `A`, which you might evaluate as `(char *) &A[3] - (char *) &A[0]`, will be three times the space for a `char *`, which would be 12 or 24 bytes in C++ implementations that use four or eight bytes for pointers to `char`, respectively.

In `*(A+1) - *A + 1`, `*(A+1)` is element 1 of the array, `A[1]`. This element is a pointer to the first byte of `"dbba"`. And `*A` is element 0 of the array, `A[0]`, which is a pointer to the first byte of `"abcx"`. As the compiler has discretion about where to put those strings, we generally cannot expect any particular relationship between them, and C++ does not define the results of subtracting these two pointers.

In C++ implementations that use a flat (simple) address space, `*(A+1) - *A + 1` may operate on the memory addresses in the natural way. (This cannot be relied upon, because a compiler does not necessarily implement this undefined expression by performing the nominally indicated arithmetic. If it recognizes the undefined behavior, optimization by the compiler may transform it into any other code.) If the arithmetic is performed in that way, and the later evaluation of `(*A+var)` is performed similarly, then the result may be effectively `*(A+1) - *A + 1 + *A` = `*(A+1) + 1`, which is a pointer to character 1 of `"dbba"` (starting from “d” as character 0). So it is unsurprising that the output is “bba”.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble , I have edited my question. Can you have a look into the question again?

Comment: ```They might be next to each other in that order, they might be in a different order, or they might be scattered and mingled with other data.```
If they are not next to each other or not contiguous in manner then how are we performing arithmetic operations on address. Am I something missing here?

Comment: Consider a C implementation that uses a flat address space—bytes of memory are numbered from 0, 1, 2, 3,… to however many bytes there are. Suppose `"abcx"` is put at location 1000. Suppose `"dbba"` is put at location 5678.  Then `"dbba" - "abcx" + 1` is 5678 − 1000 + 1 = 4679. So `var = *(A+1) - *A + 1;` would set `var` to 4679. Then `var + *A` is 4679 + 1000 = 5679, which is one byte beyond where `"dbba"` starts, so it is where `"bba"` starts.